# Ultimate CSS Gradient Code Breaking CSS

Tags: css, gradient

I copied some code for a div using Colorzilla's Ultimate CSS Generator [HERE](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

When added to my CSS file it looks like this:

```
.su-quote-shell
{
padding:20px !important;
border-radius:50px !important;
border:5px solid #fef5d6 !important;
background: #ffffff !important; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 1%, #fff4d6 100%) !important; /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#fff4d6)) !important; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 1%,#fff4d6 100%) !important; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 1%,#fff4d6 100% !important); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 1%,#fff4d6 100%) !important; /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 1%,#fff4d6 100%) !important; /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#fff4d6',GradientType=0 !important; /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Note: The padding and border code is my own

When I run my page, it seems any CSS below this section is ignored / not loaded. I'm guessing it's something to do with all the /* comments but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried removing the comments and seeing if that actually is the issue?

Comment: It's not likely to be the comments. Use your favorite webdev tool (Chrome Inspector, Firebug etc) to see if the styles are even being applied. Could you have misspelled the class name?

Comment: Check your IE6-9 CSS, you have forgotten to enclose your paranthess.
Secondly, does this issue happen on every each browser?

Comment: That's a lot of `!important`s, are they all necessary?

Comment: don't use `!important` unnecessarily...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a closing parentheses on the last line right before the `!important`:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#fff4d6',GradientType=0) !important; /* IE6-9 */
```